# Will my (encrypted) swap be erased if I re-encrypt my entire device?

Tags: luks, swap, endeavouros

I have a fully encrypted EndeavourOS installation (a variant of arch with the only difference being a GUI installer) with LUKS2. I also (obviously) have my swap space encrypted. However, I am not satisfied as my password is weak and easily brute-forcible with recent developments, and I'm dissatisfied with the defaults of the Calameres Installer on EndeavourOS (aes-128-cbc, seriously?)

I know how to re-encrypt the device with cryptsetup as I have read the entire man page of the re-encrypt parameter, but I'm worried about if it will do anything to my encrypted swap. Will I have to go through the hassle of setting up an encrypted swap drive again, or will it be sitting there as if nothing happened assuming that the re-encryption goes well without any crashes? I want to address the re-encryption to the entire device, so I presume that `dev/sdX` is the appropriate command to address it to all `/dev` locations, including swap space and all the others that I'm not worried about.

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily get rid of the weak password by adding a new one and deleting the old one. If you are afraid of AES-128-CBC: I would like to have your problems... If you use full disk encryption then I don't see how the swap configuration would be affected at all and how you could have had any "hassle of setting up an encrypted swap".